# Calculate the value of the error (only) with two decimal places for: $(5.1 \pm 0.4) / (2.5 \pm 0.2)$

Tags: approximation, error-propagation

Calculate the value of the error (only) with two decimal places for:

$Z = \frac {5.1 \pm 0.4} {2.5 \pm 0.2}$.

I tried finding $Z_{max} = \frac {5.1(1+0.078)}{2.5(1-0.08)}$ which gives $2.04 + 0.335$ and I thought $0.335$ would be the error, but I am wrong.

Please help to see where I got off the track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I get $Z_{max}=5.5/2.3\approx 2.3913$, while $Z_{nom}=5.1/2.5= 2.04$. Your answer has more than two places.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the numerator and denominator are both positive. This guarantees that $$Z_{\text{max}}=\frac{\text{numerator}_{\text{max}}}{\text{denominator}_{\text{min}}}$$ and $$Z_{\text{min}}=\frac{\text{numerator}_{\text{min}}}{\text{denominator}_{\text{max}}}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{4.7}{2.7} \leq Z\leq\frac{5.5}{2.3}$$
$$1.74(07)\leq Z \leq 2.39(13)$$

We can also calculate $Z_\text{nom}=\frac{5.1}{2.5}=2.04$. Therefore, the error is:

$$\max\{|Z_\text{nom}-1.74(07)| , |Z_\text{nom}-2.39(13)| \}$$
$$=\max\{|2.04-1.74(07)| , |2.04-2.39(13)| \}$$
$$=\max\{0.29(93) , 0.35(13) \}$$
$$= 0.35(13)$$

With two decimal places, the error appears to be $0.35$.

Comment: The reason you got off track is because the operation of division "stretches" the error on one side (where $Z>Z_\text{nom}$), while "shrinking" the error on the other side (where $Z<Z_\text{nom}$). The error that you computed relies on the assumption that the error on both sides remains balanced after division, but the actual error is chosen to be the larger of the two errors.